# How to install 32 bit XP OS and 64 bit Ubuntu in Windows 7 64 bit 7057 OS

Tags: virtualbox

Hi i want to install 32 bit windows xp or ubuntu in my windows 7 7057 version. But I am not able to do so. I do not get the option of mount dvd/cd in the left side of virtual box 3.1.2 version. Instead I get a storage icon there which has IED primary master and IED secondary master. I give the virtual disc for the former and the iso image of xp in the secondary and it is not running. I am getting the same for even Ubuntu 64 os image. Kindly help me. Virtualisation is supported in my machine.

Answer (score 1):

Go in to settings for the virtual machine and make sure that you have a optical drive. If not add one.

Then simply select the optical drive on the left hand side and choose the iso to mount, or the physical optical drive.

[image]